# Send image file to AWS Lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to send one image to my Lambda Function using Python just to test for one project, but Postman is giving me one error and I don't know how to solve it.

My code is simply to detect if I have some data in the key **"image"** and return some message. I'm using Postman to send the POST request, I clicked in the **Body** tab, selected the form-data option and I wrote **image** for the key and selected the image file from my computer (the image size is 27 kb). This is the code in my Lambda Function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event['image']:
        return {
            "Message": 'Everything went ok'
        }
```

And this is the error message that I'm receiving from Postman:

> { "message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected
> character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to
> follow minus sign, for valid numeric value\n at [Source:
> (byte[])"----------------------------137965576541301454606184\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="TestImage.png"\r\nContent-Type:
> image/png\r\n\r\n�PNG\r\n\n ... }

Comment: Do you use API gateway for that? Images should be set as binary playloads and encoded into base64.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, I converted my images to base64 and then sent it to the server

Comment: Thanks for letting me know:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve that problem, I needed to set my Camera to convert the image to **base64** and then upload it to the server.

In the server, I convert it again and then work with it as I want. Base64 is a group of binary-to-text encoding schemes that represent binary data in an ASCII string format by translating it into a radix-64 representation.

So, you will convert your image to string and then sending it, it was the best way that I found to upload my images.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this. I was using Postman, getting UnidentifiedImageError. The below worked.

**Posting the Image:**

```
data = open('x.jpg','rb').read()
data = base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf8")
r = requests.post('url',data=data)
```

**Processing on the function side**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
image_bytes = event['body'].encode('utf-8')
img_b64dec = base64.b64decode(image_bytes)
img_byteIO = BytesIO(img_b64dec)
image = Image.open(img_byteIO)
```

Answer (score 0):

@itsprit's answer didn't quite work for me; I found that I had to use json.dumps before posting the data:

```
data = base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf8")
file = json.dumps({'image':data})
r = requests.post(DETECTION_URL,data=file)
```

and then on the lambda function side, the "event" variable will have the same keys as the input 'file' variable, so another slight modification:

```
image_bytes = event['image'].encode('utf-8')
```